# "What do you think about?" or "What you think about?"

Tags: questions, do-support

Which of the following is correct?

> "What do you think about?"
>
> "What you think about?"

Comment: Mind elaborating on your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For formal communication, you need a verb: *"What **do** you think about autumn?"* or, *"What **are** you thinking about now?"*

In informal communication, you can get by without it, but the wording would have a very slangy (if not uneducated) feel:

> What you think about the new uniforms?
>   Love 'em - they are epic!

Incidentally, when spoken, the first line of that dialog would probably sound something like this: *"**Whatchu** think about the new uniforms?"*

Comment: Really? "what you" becomes "whatchu"...most trolling I ever heard :D

Comment: @Mistu4u - Yes, really! Sometimes it's spelled _whatcha_, and sometimes _whatchu_, when whoever is writing it wants to highlight how the words _what_ and _you_ are being slurred together. One rather famous example is mentioned in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Coleman#Diff.27rent_Strokes): _Coleman became the most popular fixture of the show, enhanced by his character's catchphrase **"What'chu talkin' 'bout,** Willis?"_ You can find examples of that utterance all over YouTube, like in [this montage](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFhLNxkXa6Y).

Comment: Reminds me of the film Cloud Atlas, it was a headache to understand Tom Hank and Hale Berry's pronunciation in a distant future :P Every word was either preceded by `'` or followed by `'`

Comment: Yes, "what you" becomes "whatchu" or "whatcha" with regularity in informal conversations. In fact, "Whatcha gonna do?" was the title of a hit single in 1977 by the band Pablo Cruise.